# Is the result given by NSolve sufficiently reliable to claim that there is such a solution for the equation?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I use this code for `ContourPlot`

```
f := Cos[4 x] + (7 Sin[4 x])/( 2 x) + (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] -  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[ 4 x] + ((7 + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 2 x Cos[y] Csc[7 x]) Sin[4 x])/( 2 x))^2];
g := Cos[4 x] + ((11 + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 2 x Cos[y] Csc[7 x]) Sin[4 x])/(  2 x);

ContourPlot[  f == g , {x, 7 , 7.4  }, {y, 0 , 1 },  FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 30, 
 RegionFunction ->  Function[{x, y}, (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) >  1 - (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] - Cos[4 x] ]]
```

and I get this plot

[image]

I want to check whether there are solutions for small values of $y$ which is not clear in the plot. Using `NSolve` for $y=0.02$, I get an answer without warning or eror

```
y := 2/100  ;
NSolve[ f == g  &&    (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) >  1 - (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] - Cos[4 x]   &&  71801/10000   < x < 71809/10000   , x   ] 

(* {{x -> 7.18078}} *)
```

**Question**
Is this result reliable that there exists a solution at the point $(x,y)=( 7.18078,0.02)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Plot3D` shows the solutions `f==g`  (without restricted region)

```
pic = Plot3D[ f - g  , {x, 7.1 , 7.4}, { y, -Pi, Pi},MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Red} , PlotRange -> {-.5, .5} , PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None ]
```

[image]

The  solution found by `Plot3D`

```
pi = Cases[Normal[pic], Line[p_] :> p, All] ; (* solution points found*)
```

must be member of the restricted region

```
cond = (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) >1 - (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] - Cos[4 x]
```

Only part `sol` (plotted in blue)

```
sol = Solve[(7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) == 1 - (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] - Cos[4 x], Cos[y]][[1]]
(*{Cos[y] < ((7 + 2 x Cot[4 x] + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 2 x Csc[4 x]) Sin[7 x])/(2 x)}*)

pplot = ParametricPlot[{{x, ArcCos[Cos[y]]}, {x, -ArcCos[Cos[y]]}} /.sol, {x, 7.1, 7.4}, PlotRange -> {{7.1, 7.4}, {-Pi, Pi}},AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Blue]; 


Show[{RegionPlot[cond , {x, 7. , 7.4}, { y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> {100 }, MaxRecursion -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 25], Graphics[{Red, Map[Point[#[[All, 1 ;; 2]]] &, pi ]}],pplot}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

is a permissible solution , which confirms your `NSolve`-result.

Comment: Thanks.  Does your answer imply that we should always check the results obtained by NSolve? Or, in general, if NSolve gives an answer, it is definitely a solution?   @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: @math2021 Usually `NSolve` gives reliable answers. Your example shows, that `ContourPlot`  sometimes misses parts of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

To the question "Is this result reliable that there exists a solution at the point (x,y)=(7.18078,0.02)?", the answer is "No".  The results shown below indicate $(x,y)$ = (7.18078, 0.02) is ***not a reliable result***.  To the title question "Is the result given by NSolve sufficiently reliable to claim that there is such a solution for the equation?", the answer is "that can depend on the working precision".

First, a quick sanity check at the point in question.

```
f = Cos[4 x] + (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) + (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] *
      Sin[4 x] - Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[4 x] + ((7 + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 
         2 x Cos[y] Csc[7 x]) Sin[4 x])/(2 x))^2];
g = Cos[4 x] + ((11 + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 2 x Cos[y] Csc[7 x]) * 
       Sin[4 x])/(2 x);

{g, f, g - f} /. x -> 7.18078 /. y -> 0.02

(*  {2.63053, 0.188162, 2.44236}  *)
```

Since $g-f$ is not small at $(x,y)$ = (7.18078, 0.02), in comparison to $g$ and $f$, we do not have a solution for $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$.

Consider the domain of $f$ when $x$ = 7.18078.

```
domain = FunctionDomain[f /. x -> Rationalize[7.18078], y];
% /. C[1] -> 0 // N // Simplify

(*  0.0147881 <= y <= 6.2684 || -0.00341194 <= y <= 0.00341194  *)
```

Use the `domain` with `NSolve` to get better values for $y$ that give $x$= 7.18078.

```
soln = NSolve[{g == f /. x -> Rationalize[7.18078], 0 < y, 
    domain /. C[1] -> 0}] // Flatten  

(* {y -> 0.00329973, y -> 0.0148135, y -> 6.26837} *)
```

There are three solutions, but the first solution is not in the region of interest and the third solution is too large. So, we only consider the second solution.

Perform the sanity check with the new values of $y$

```
{f, g, g - f} /. x -> 7.18078 /. soln[[2]]
(*  {0.886432, 0.886432, 3.49618*10^-9}  *)
```

So for $x$=7.18078 there is a solution at $y$=0.0148135.  Here is a plot of $f$ and $g$ vs $y$ for $x$=7.18078.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f, g} /. x -> Rationalize[7.18078]], {y, 0.0, 0.025},
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Black] & /@
    {"Y", "f(x,y), g(x,y)", 
     "Functions f,g plotted with x=7.18078"}),
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}]
```

[image]

#### Edit:

To my surprise, $(x,y)$=(7.180777360457, 0.02) passes the sanity check and should be considered a solution.

```
{f, g, g - f} /. x -> 7.180777360457 /. y -> 0.02
(*  {0.886435, 0.886435, 1.73334*10^-7}  *)
```

One way to obtain the precision required to pass the sanity check it to evaluate

```
y = 2/100;
f = Cos[4 x] + (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) + (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] *
      Sin[4 x] - Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[4 x] + ((7 + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 
         2 x Cos[y] Csc[7 x]) Sin[4 x])/(2 x))^2];
g = Cos[4 x] + ((11 + 2 x Cot[7 x] - 2 x Cos[y] Csc[7 x]) * 
       Sin[4 x])/(2 x);
 
 NSolve[f == g && (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) > 
     1 - (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] - Cos[4 x] && 
    7.1807`30 < x < 7.1808`30, x] // Flatten

(*  {x -> 7.18077736045694285104818990199}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are <s>three</s> four tests:

First, define `x0` to be the OP's root:

```
Block[{y = 2/100},
  NSolve[
   f == g && (7 Sin[4 x])/(2 x) > 
     1 - (-Cos[y] + Cos[7 x]) Csc[7 x] Sin[4 x] - Cos[4 x] && 
    71801/10000 < x < 71809/10000, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
  ];
x0 = x /. First[%]

(*  7.18078  *)
```

The make-a-graph (MAG) approach suggested there was trouble!  But adjusting `r0` down to `1/10^8` led to success.  I guess it should have been enough to confirm it, but the trouble below led me to do extra checks:

```
Block[{y = 2/100, r0 = 1/10^3},
 Plot[f - g, {x, x0 - r0, x0 + r0}
  (*,PlotRange -> All*)]
 ]
```

[image]

Extra check 1: $\int_\gamma f'(x)\;dx/f(x) / (2\pi i)$ counts the roots of $f(x)$ inside the contour $\gamma$.  There is one inside the circle of radius `r0 = 1/10^8` centered on the root.

```
Block[{y = 2/100, int, r0 = 1/10^8},
 int = Identity[D[#, x]/# &[f - g]] Dt[x] /. x -> x0 + r0*Exp[I t] /. 
   Dt[t] -> 1;
 NIntegrate[
   int,
   {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   Method -> "Trapezoidal"]/(2 I Pi)
 ]

(*  1. - 7.36497*10^-15 I  *)
```

Extra check 2: The intermediate value theorem shows there is at least one root between `x0 ± r0`.  This is roughly the same as plotting, but using only two function evaluations.

```
Block[{y = 2/100, int, r0 = 1/10^15, x0 = SetPrecision[x0, 32]},
 f - g /. {{x -> x0 - r0}, {x -> x0 + r0}}
 ]

(*  {4.13715437561*10^-9, -1.90625909611*10^-9}  *)
```

Extra check 3: Confirm with `FindRoot`.

```
Block[{y = 2/100, int, r0 = 1/10^8},
 FindRoot[f - g, {x, x0 - r0, x0 + r0}
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
 ]
x - x0 /. %
(*
  {x -> 7.18078}
  8.88178*10^-16
*)
```

Actually, I checked everything with `WorkingPrecision -> 100` — higher precision is another way to confirm — and redid the make-a-graph check with `PlotRange -> All`, which diminished the confusion my initial graphs caused me.